# Docker refuses to curl on 443

Tags: docker, ubuntu, centos7

I am experiencing a network issue with docker that I haven't seen before. Could it be related to my ubuntu network conf? or docker setup?

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  36.86kB
Step 1/2 : FROM centos:centos7
 ---> 5e35e350aded
Step 2/2 : RUN curl https://google.com/
 ---> Running in d65fe6ad9d57
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2a00:1450:4007:808::200e: Cannot assign requested address
```

regards

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-connect-to-https-443-from-a-docker-image/5112/3

Comment: I tried that approach but it didn't work.

Comment: curl is trying to contact google on its ipv6 address. Does your host have an ipv6 connection to the outside world ?

Comment: you were right @Zeitounator

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the network I was using provided by my cellphone (an Android hotspot on a Xiaomi redmi7). I still cannot figure out the real cause of this misfunctionality.